# Debian: Install `kchmviewr` download a lot of packages, remove them just a few kb

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies

I am not using kde desktop enviroment(lxde instead), and I download `kchmviewer` via `apt-get  install kchmviewer`. It downloaded a lot of packages and takes up space about `200M`. However when I uninstall the packages via `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove kchmviewer` it doesn't remove the packages installed alongside the install. It only removes hundreds of `kb`. I think I did right way, usually `--purge autoremove` will remove all the packages alongside the install, but not this case.

**How can I remove all the package that actually I don't need, it is annoying to have them installed but can't remove them.**

Answer (score 0):

Use deborphan:

```
apt-get remove `deborphan`
```

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Then you have no unnecessary packages. You may try `deborphan  --guess-all`.

Comment: But how could this be? I installed 200M packages, and now remove just a few kb. guess-all doesn't work also, only two packages removed.

Comment: dpkg and apt have logs at `/var/log/dpkg.log` and `/var/log/apt`. Look at the history.

Comment: Then a new question comes around: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311012/how-to-easisly-uninstall-the-packages-listed-in-the-history

Answer (score 0):

The following command will remove packages installed as dependencies which are no longer needed

```
apt-get autoremove
```